# i3 Black Screen, with Mouse but no shortcuts working (Manjaro KDE)

Tags: kde, manjaro, window-manager, i3

After successfully installing Manjaro KDE without any problems, I proceeded to install i3 WM. Again, no problems when switching manually through SDDM, and I've also tweaked some of i3 configurations successfully. However, when I changed the autologin session — through KDE — to i3, now I receive a black screen with no functionality, and a mouse cursor, which features KDE's theme.

I suspected it was a problem with my `.xinitrc`, but I'm not sure. My `.xinitrc` comes from a previous Arch install from some time ago, which was working. I've also tried to use the `get_session()` function in the [standard KDE `.xinitrc`](https://github.com/ComplexPlatform/KDE-dotfiles/blob/master/.xinitrc), but it didn't work either. Here's what I've been using:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

xset r rate 300 40
xset s off
xset -dpms
imwheel

pacman -Sy &
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap

exec i3
```

How do I even debug this? (I don't think this is a graphics driver problem, since both i3 and KDE were working fine a few steps before this happened...)

Answer (score 1):

any chance `imwheel` is not available and your `.xinitrc` crashes at that point?

any output in `~/.xsession-errors`?

(wanted to comment, but not privileged enough here to do that..)

Comment: I did install `imwheel`, but I'll check again in the `.xsession-errors`, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I haven't found any `xsession-errors` actually. Interestingly I've found out that going into the TTY and then starting X (`startx`) works perfectly fine. I've also tried to create an `.xsession` file with `startx` inside to see if it worked but it didn't. In my previous Arch install, I remembered that I was using `startx` inside my `.bash_profile`, but that didn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: `.xsessionrc` with `startx` inside wouldn't do any good - X session load that file on startup (and `startx` would create a new X session, which would load this file again, ...)

Comment: what happens when you do not have any `.xsessionrc` in your home directory?

Comment: oh and at least I'm confused rn about `.xinitrc` vs `.xsessionrc` - also, you tried adding startx to a `.xsession` - double check file names

Comment: I didn't use session files in the past, only `.xinitrc`. At any rate, I've tested all the variations and none have worked (with and without `startx`, with and without `xsessionrc`).

Comment: what happens when you are in that state, go to a virtual terminal (e.g. CTRL+F1), log into the same user account and then run `DISPLAY=:0 i3`?

Comment: In that state, all I see is a mouse matching KDE's theme and a black screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't seem to do anything. I use at least <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> in order to launch a new TTY. In a new TTY, running `sudo DISPLAY=:0 i3` gives me back `Authorizatio required, but no authorization protocol specified. i3: Cannot open display`>

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I've run into the same issue but with Kubuntu 22.10. Did you ever resolve this?